# Confused on how to use accesscode

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to figure out how to use the access code for a signer.  In the api there is the accesscode field and a addaccesscodetoemail field.  If I want the signer to see the accesscode in the email, do I just set that value to the accesscode and then set addaccesscodetoemail = true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, If you want the signer to see the accesscode in the email, then you just set that value to the accesscode and then set addaccesscodetoemail = true and signer will see the accesscode in the email itself. But it is not a good practice as it defeats the purpose of using the accesscode. Ideally, you should set accesscode via API and then communicate accesscode to the signer via another channel (not by sending the accesscode in an envelope notification email).

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign's `Access code` authentication is similar to `sms` authentication except that for access code it's up to the sender to determine how to actually get the code over to the recipient.

They can send their own SMS outside of DocuSign platform with the code, they can send their own custom email, call the person, etc - but the bottom line is that DocuSign will not include the code in the system generated email.

To configure an access code for a recipient you have to set it on the specific type of recipient, in this case `signer` for example:

```
"recipients": 
 {
    "signers": [
     {
        "email": "test_1@email.com",
        "name": "Name 1",
        "accessCode": "1234",

        ...
```

Comment: So if I set addaccesscodetoemail = true, will the access code be included in the email body for that recipient?

Comment: This was answered by Amit below but both answers are good!  Thanks @Ergin